# Bug: Writing multi-line formulas does not work in the "learn more" editor

Tags: bug

##### Bug / Problem

I just edited a tag or suggested an edit. I noticed that line breaks in formulas don't work. Normally in $\LaTeX$ you write a `\\` for a line break. In the tag editor, however, there is no line break. No, it writes a $x$ instead.

E.G.

```
\begin{align*}
r &= \left| z \right| = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}\\
\varphi &= \operatorname{arctan2}\left( y,\, x \right) = \arg\left( z \right)\\
x &= r \cdot \cos\left( \varphi \right)\\
y &= r \cdot \sin\left( \varphi \right)
\end{align*}
```

$$
\begin{align*}
r &= \left| z \right| = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}\\
\varphi &= \operatorname{arctan2}\left( y,\, x \right) = \arg\left( z \right)\\
x &= r \cdot \cos\left( \varphi \right)\\
y &= r \cdot \sin\left( \varphi \right)
\end{align*}
$$

looks like this:

[image]

but it shoul look like this:

[image]

You could simply say, then just write single-line formulas, but that becomes difficult if you write matrices and want to remain clear at the same time...

The problem appears everywhere on my site, but only here. Not on the other SE pages.

##### My Stuff

My Browser is: *Version 113.0.5672.127 (Official Build) (64-Bit)*

My divise is: A Laptop with:

Edition:    Windows 10 Pro

Version:    21H2

Buiild:     19044.2965

Power:      Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0

Comment: Try using four backslashes instead of two? That sometimes works for me. Some related posts on Meta SE: ["MathJax escape sequences don't work"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387653) and user3840170's [answer to "Why aren't two subscripts in same line allowed in MathJax?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387100). Also, you only mention the browser version: is the browser Chrome?